# What does `int const a[5]` really mean?

Tags: c, arrays, constants, lvalue

Consider the following array declaration:

```
int const a[5];
```

From the semantic standpoint of the language, is it exactly equivalent to `const int a[5]`? Assuming that is the case, both declarations would essentially read like "*a is an array of 5 constant ints*".

The alternative way to read the first declaration would be "*a is a constant array of 5 ints*".

Obviously, both of the statements logically imply that the whole array is constant; if an array consists of 5 constant ints, then the entire array is constant. Alternatively, if the whole array is constant, then all of its values are also constant.

I am aware that the notion of a "constant array" is a bit meaningless since arrays are not modifiable lvalues (that is, they cannot appear on the left side of an assignment). However, are there any circumstances under which these two declarations would yield different behaviour?

([Cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/) rejects the first declaration as a syntax error, while most current compilers accept it.)

EDIT:

The linked duplicate asks whether the order of `const` matters for ordinary variables. With arrays, it is a bit more confusing, so I don't consider this a duplicate.

Comment: `const` applies to the type to it's left, unless it's the first in the declaration, in which case it applies to the right. So the both are equivalent.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633776/constant-array-of-constant-objects?
Regardless, this doesn't really mean anything. The `5` is already a constant here. When using `const int a[5];` it would give you a constant array in `C++`. Note that this does not work (correctly) in `C`! So for C it's pretty much ignored.

Comment: They are the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162480/const-int-vs-int-const-as-function-parameter-in-c-and-c

Comment: "The 5 is already a constant here." -- irrelevant. "this doesn't really mean anything" -- wrong. " Note that this does not work (correctly) in C!" -- wrong. "So for C it's pretty much ignored." -- wrong. You misunderstand the question you cite (which is different from this) and Kerrick SB's answer.

Comment: "However, are there any circumstances under which these two declarations would yield different behaviour?" -- the keyword order is a matter of *syntax* -- it has no bearing on the semantics. "Cdecl.org rejects the first declaration as a syntax error" -- then it's broken.

Comment: C declarations are read inside out. So this says that `a` is an array of 5 const ints. Changing the order says that `a` is an array of 5 int consts, which is meaningless, but C allows you to put const first because the language designers were confused and did their best to spread that confusion.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> is it exactly equivalent to `const int a[5]`

Yes, it is.

> The alternative way to read the first declaration would be "a is a constant array of 5 ints".

Not really. Your declaration, as written, applies `const` to array elements specifically. In order to apply the `const` to the array itself (as opposed to applying it to the array elements), you'd have to do something like

```
int (const a)[5];
```

but such declaration is syntactically invalid in C.

An indirect attempt to apply `const` to the array itself can be made through an intermediate typedef

```
typedef int A[5];
const A a;
```

but in this case, per language rules, the `const` qualifier "falls through" to array elements and the whole thing is just equivalent to

```
const int a[5];
```

Note, again, that `const A a;` above is not *immediately* equivalent to `const int a[5];`. It is actually equivalent to the aforementioned `int (const a)[5];` (!). (It is a legal way to sneak `int (const a)[5];` past compiler's defenses.) But that `int (const a)[5];` is very-short lived - it gets immediately transformed into `const int a[5];` by the compiler.

> if an array consists of 5 constant ints, then the entire array is constant. Alternatively, if the whole array is constant, then all of its values are also constant.

Well, that is not entirely true. C language does differentiate between the array object itself and its elements. Conceptually, these are different entities. For example, as you noted yourself, the language spec says that arrays are *non-modifiable lvalues*. This, of course, does not prevent array elements to be modifiable.

This conceptual distinction between array as a whole and individual array elements, combined with the "fall through" behavior for `const` is exactly what leads to the following unpleasant situation

```
typedef int A[5];
A a;
const A *p = &a; // ERROR!!!
```

i.e. it breaks the "normal" const-correctness rule that allows us to initialize `const T *` pointers with `T *` values. (C++ deliberately updated it const-correctness rules to make the above code to behave "as expected", but C insists on rejecting it.)

Answer (score 1):

I put this together:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int const a[5];
    const int b[5];
    int c[5];

    a[0] = 1;
    b[0] = 2;
    c = a;
    c = b;
}
```

And gcc (4.1.2) spit out this:

```
gcc -o /tmp/x2 /tmp/x2.c
/tmp/x2.c: In function ‘main’:
/tmp/x2.c:9: error: assignment of read-only location
/tmp/x2.c:10: error: assignment of read-only location
/tmp/x2.c:11: error: incompatible types in assignment
/tmp/x2.c:12: error: incompatible types in assignment
```

So at least based on this there doesn't appear to be any distinction.

Comment: I did the same experiment prior to asking the question, but it still doesn't rule out any potential differences between the two.