# constant elements vs. constant array

Tags: c, arrays, constants, typedef

Everybody knows how to declare an array with constant elements:

```
const int a[10];
```

Apparently, it is also possible to declare an array that is *itself* constant, via a `typedef`:

```
typedef int X[10];
const X b;
```

From a technical and a practical standpoint, do `a` and `b` have the same type or different types?

Comment: Arrays can't be assigned to *anyway*.

Comment: An array can have constant elements, the size of array is compile time constant.. but what does a constant array even mean? M curious.

Comment: constant and const have different meaning in C.

Comment: A similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31412972/what-does-int-const-a5-really-mean

Comment: @BlagovestBuyukliev It's not a similar question, I think it is a duplicate. But the answerer seems to imply that the array itself is "const", which is not true.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Apparently, it is also possible to declare an array that is itself constant

Nope. In N1256, §6.7.3/8:

> If the specification of an array type includes any type qualifiers, the element type is so-qualified, not the array type.<sup>118)</sup>

Then footnote 118 says:

> Both of these can occur through the use of `typedefs`.

Answer (score 4):

They have the same type, though clang will print them differently. Since the array itself cannot be `const`, it is said to "fall through".

For the non-typedefed version, clang prints the type as `const int [10]`. For the typedef version, it prints `int const[10]`. Both of those are equivalent.

[Coliru in action](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/82b98974c705660d).

Answer (score 1):

Ran some tests:

```
typedef int X[10];

#define typeinfo(t) _Generic((t), \
  X: "int X[10]", \
  int: "int", \
  int *: "int *", \
  const int *: "const int *", \
  default: "not" \
  )

int main(void) {
  const int a[10];
  const X b;

  printf("%zu\n", sizeof (const int *));
  puts(typeinfo(a));
  puts(typeinfo(b));
  printf("%zu\n", sizeof a);
  printf("%zu\n", sizeof b);
  puts(typeinfo(a[0]));
  puts(typeinfo(b[0]));
  printf("%zu\n", sizeof a[0]);
  printf("%zu\n", sizeof b[0]);
}
```

Output

```
4
const int *
const int *
40
40
int
int
4
4
```

Both have the same size and both convert to the same type when passed as an argument.  Neither is a pointer.  Both are arrays.

By code analysis and testing - they are the same type.

Comment: They are also the same type by definition!