# Const arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, constants

Original question:
If I define:

```
const int z[5] = {10, 11, 12, 13, 14};
```

does it mean:

1. it's a constant array of integers i.e. the address which z points to is always constant and can never change, but the elements of z can change.

OR

2. Each element of z is a constant i.e. their value can never change.

Edit:

More info:

There is another variable:

```
const int *y = z;
func((int *) y);
```

where func is defined as:

```
void func(int y[]) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        y[i] = i; //y[i] can be set to any integer; used i as example
    }
}
```

where in func, using y, the array is traversed and each element is changed. Is this is valid even though all elements of z are const?

Comment: Did you try changing `z[0]`?

Comment: The address that `z` points to can never change anyway. In any case, you can use http://cdecl.org/

Comment: Cross reference [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7633776/constant-array-of-constant-objects)

Comment: @Amit Yes, I was able to change z[0]. I used to think the definition meant the meaning #2. But since I was able to change z[0], I am confused now.

Comment: Actually only the programmer guarantees for each value not to write to it. Nothing less, nothing more. Wheter the compiler will really use read-only memory is not defined by the standard. This becomes instantly clear when using this as a function argument. You can still pass non-`const` values.

Comment: @sandeeps Sounds like your compiler is broken.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Given that declaration, any attempt to modify `z[0]` should have been rejected by the compiler. Please update your question with a complete self-contained example that demonstrates this.

Comment: @juanchopanza: That's doubtful. It's far more likely that the OP has made a mistake somewhere.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, that is what I was actually trying to say, in my own special way :-)

Comment: @Olaf: A compiler *will* reject attempts to modify `const` objects (though you can bypass those checks with, for example, pointer casts).

Comment: @KeithThompson: I did not say different. However, if you really want to break the contract (e.g. by casting away `const`), the compiler will not hinder you. (but gcc still warns). C does not have true constants.

Comment: @KeithThompson I have added more info to my question.

Comment: How is `func` declared? If it's something like `void func(int *arg)`, then you should get *at least* a warning on the call.

Comment: No, what does the declaration of `func` look like?

Comment: @KeithThompson I am writing it, I accidentally pressed the enter key earlier and it posted the incomplete statement.

Comment: You don't get a compiler warning because you cast the value of `y` to `int*`. You're telling the compiler to *pretend* that `y` points to non-`const` data. Since in fact `y` points to `const` data, you have lied to the compiler, and your code has undefined behavior. Casts, especially pointer casts, should usually be avoided.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90270/discussion-between-sandeeps-and-keith-thompson).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

It means that each element of `z` is read-only.

The object `z` is an array object, not a pointer object; it doesn't point to anything. Like any object, the address of `z` does not change during its lifetime.

Since the *object* `z` is an array, the *expression* `z`, in most but not all contexts, is implicitly converted to a pointer expression, pointing to `z[0]`. That address, like the address of the entire array object `z`, doesn't change during the object's lifetime. This "conversion" is a compile-time adjustment to the meaning of the expression, not a run-time type conversion.

To understand the (often confusing) relationship between arrays and pointers, read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com/).

It's important to understand that "constant" and `const` are two different things.

If something is *constant*, it's evaluated at compile time; for example, `42` and `(2+2)` are *constant expressions*.

If an object is defined with the `const` keyword, that means that it's read-only, not (necessarily) that it's constant. It means that you can't attempt to modify the object via its name, and attempting to modify it by other means (say, by taking its address and casting to a non-const pointer) has undefined behavior. Note, for example, that this:

```
const int r = rand();
```

is valid. `r` is read-only, but its value cannot be determined until run time.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by: "`z` is an array, **not a pointer**; it doesn't point to anything" and then "Since `z` is an array...is implicitly **converted to a pointer** to `z[0]` " Is it a pointer or not?

Comment: @simplicisveritatis: An array is not a pointer. Try taking the sizes of both. But the **name** of the array is implicitly converted to a pointer to the first element for most uses.

Comment: A `const` object in C (different from C++) is not necessarily read-only. It is left to the implementation if there is any write-protection to the object. `const` is only a guarantee by the programmer not to write to the object. The compiler can rely on this contract. There are other languages, there is no practical difference between a constant and a literal.

Comment: @simplicisveritatis: If it were already a pointer, it wouldn't need to be *converted* to a pointer. An array object contains a contiguous sequence of elements. A pointer object contains a single address. They're completely different things. Again, please read section 6 of the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://www.c-faq.com); it explains this in more detail than I have time for.

Comment: @Olaf: A `const` object is read-only in the sense that any attempt to modify it via its declared name is a constraint violation, and any attempt to modify it otherwise has undefined behavior.

Comment: @KeithThompson: Right. But the compiler will not keep you from trying (this is useful for e.g. MCUs with data in Flash for updates - **if you know what you do**). Other languages OTOH will not allow such write under any circumstances, i.e. prevent you actively from breaking the contract.

Comment: @Keith Thompson I just wanted to address and clarify this apparent ambiguity in two consecutive sentences of the answer you provide. :)  The rest is crystal clear.

Comment: @simplicisveritatis: Ok. Are those two sentences clear now?

Comment: @Keith Thompson absolutely! :)

Answer (score 1):

### In your case the answer is:

> 2. Each element of z is a constant i.e. their value can never change.

You can't create a `const` array because arrays are objects and can only be created at runtime and `const` entities are resolved at compile time.

So, the `const` **is interpreted as in the first example below**, i.e. applied for the elements of the array. Which means that the following are equivalent:
<sup>The array in your example needs to be initialized.</sup>

```
 int const z[5] = { /*initial (and only) values*/};
 const int z[5] = { /*-//-*/ };
```

It is some type [commutative property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) of the `const` specifier and the type-specifier, in your example `int`.

Here are few examples to clarify the usage of constant:

1.Constant integers definition: (can not be reassigned). In the below two expression the use of `const` is equivalent:

```
int const a = 3;  // after type identifier
const int b = 4;  // equivalent to before type qualifier
```

2.Constant pointer definition (no pointer arithmetics or reassignment allowed):

```
int * const p = &anInteger;  // non-constant data, constant pointer
```

and pointer definition to a constant `int` (the value of the pointed integer cannot be changed, but the pointer can):

```
const int *p = &anInteger;  // constant data, non-constant pointer
```

Comment: since when can an array only be "created" at runtime, in C ? If you define it as an array of const values then it will be created at compile time.

Comment: "`const` entities are resolved at compile time". This is false. For example, `const int r = rand();` is valid, but the value is evaluated in runtime