# Set an element of a `const` array as the length of another array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, c++11, constants

I defined a `const int` array like this :

```
const int arr[] = { 100 , 200, 300, 400 };
```

Now i want to set one of the elements of above array as the length of another array like the following :

```
char buffer[arr[3]];
```

But it gave me a compile time `error` :

> ```
> non-constant arguments or reference to a non-constant symbol
> ```

I studied this [**This question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32705419/const-arrays-in-c)  to solve my problem but i became confuse about these questions :

- Why can't i set an element of a `const` array as the length of another array?
- Are the elements of a `const` array *constant* or read only?
- What is the differences between a `const` and *read only* statements in c?

Regards!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are really two different kinds of constant "things" in C++.

The one that you know as the `const` keyword: you can't modify it ***at runtime***.

And the one that's known as a constant value to the compiler ***at compile time***.

That one would be:

```
constexpr int arr[] = { 100 , 200, 300, 400 };
```

C++ requires an array size to be a `constexpr` expression, and not just a `const` one. Some compilers let you get away with just a `const` size (and not even that, actually), but that's not the current C++ standard.

You might be wondering why, in this case, this is not a constant value at compile time. After all: it's right there. It's three digits. An integer. It can't go anywhere.

Well, that would be a different, pedantic question, but is mostly irrelevant. Your compiler is well within its rights to reject a non-`constexpr` expression in this case, as ill-formed. So it does. And you have no choice but to obey your compiler's demands.

Comment: I can't modify const and constexpr in compile and either in runtime. Where's the difference????. Can you explain it more clearly?

Comment: I posted a new answer. please check out my answer.

Comment: constexpr should really be renamed reallyconst, and const therefor be named maybeconstunlessyoudontwantittobe.. One of my favourite rants.

Answer (score 0):

I realized `const` and `constexpr` in the following statements :

- `const` : To be evaluated at ***runtime*** and it's accepted by compiler and can't change in runtime.

  ```
  const int a = std::cin.get();       // correct
  const int b = 5;                    // correct
  ```
- `constexpr` : To be evaluate at ***compile time***

  ```
  constexpr int b = std::cin.get();   // incorrect (because it evaluate in compile time, so compiler cannot forecast the value at compile time)
  constexpr int b = 65;               // correct
  ```

Now in my `code` as i understood, i think the `char buffer` is evaluate the array size at ***compile time*** and `const int arr` will be avaluate at ***runtime***. so cannot set `char buffer` array length with a number that will be evaluate at ***runtime*** and we need a *constant* value.

**Notice :**

```
const int arr[] = { 100 , 200, 300, 400 };     // Evaluate at runtime
char buffer[arr[3]];                           // Evaluate at compile time and cause error
```

So we need a `const` number that evaluated at ***compile time*** to set array length of the `char buffer` :

```
constexpr int arr[] = { 100 , 200, 300, 400 };     // Evaluate at compile time
char buffer[arr[3]];                               // Evaluate at compile time
```